# Dynamic binding giving error

Tags: c#, wcf

I dont want to use web.config to refer the bindings. So i have created dynamic bindings

```
WSHttpBinding httpBinding = new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential, true);
            httpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None;
            httpBinding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.UserName;
            httpBinding.Security.Message.EstablishSecurityContext = false;
            EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress("https:myservice/service.svc);
            myService = new ServiceClient(httpBinding, address);
            if (myService .ClientCredentials != null)
            {
                myService .ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "xxx";
                myService .ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "dfdf";
            }
```

But when i invoke it then i get error

> Cannot establish a reliable session without secure conversation. Enable secure conversation.

What is wrong with this approach?